# c++ issue with function to check if tree is full

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes

So I have a function to check if a tree is a full(if every node only has either 0 or 2 children). Every other function works and the problem is with this one (second one just calls helper). First user inputs string and it gets sorted in order(works). char at position: len/2 is turned into root and calls recursively to make rest of tree(works tried displaying). When running the code no matter what string input I provide, I get Tree is not full. Any help is appreciated. 
additional note: if commented lines are uncommented, the problem reverses and I constantly get Tree is full for every input. 
Can provide code for other functions if needed.

inputs I have tried:
rats -> arst (root node r) shouldn't be full
victorn -> cinortv (root node o) should be full

```
bool isFullTreehelper(TreeNode* R00t) 
{

    //if empty tree then true
    if (R00t == NULL)
        return true;

    //leaf node
    if (R00t->left == NULL && R00t->right == NULL)
        return true;

    //if (R00t->left != NULL && R00t->right != NULL)
        //return true;


    if ((R00t->left != NULL) && (R00t->right != NULL))
    return (isFullTreehelper(R00t->left) && isFullTreehelper(R00t->right));

    return false;

}


//update: addditonal code (currently checking to see if this creates a balanced tree)

TreeNode* sortedArrayToBST_helper(ItemType items[], int start, int end)
{
    // continue while this branch has values to process
    if (start > end)
        return NULL;
        // Get the middle element and make it root
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    TreeNode* head = new TreeNode(items[mid]);
    // Recursively construct the left subtree
    // and make it left child of root
    head->left = sortedArrayToBST_helper(items, start, mid - 1);
    // Recursively construct the right subtree
    // and make it right child of root
    head->right = sortedArrayToBST_helper(items, mid + 1, end);
    return head;
}

void TreeType::sortedArrayToBST(ItemType items[], int l)
{
    root = sortedArrayToBST_helper(items, 0, l);

    //debug lines
    //cout << root->info << endl;
    //cout << root->left->info << endl;
    //cout << root->right->info << endl;
    //cout << root->left->left->info << endl;
    //cout << root->left->right->info << endl;
    //cout << root->right->left->info << endl;
    //cout << root->right->right->info << endl;

}
```

Comment: `R00t` as an argument is cute but not in a good way.

Comment: How is a tree "full" if it has no children? Do you mean "empty?"

Comment: yea if the root is null then its considered "full", its the base case (no idea why but everyone uses this definition)

Comment: Is it possible that your code for creating the tree isn't balancing the tree? I mean "cinortv " is only full if the tree is balanced, if not then it's not.

Comment: Fair enough. In C++ try and use `nullptr` in preference to `NULL`. You should also have a class that you can organize these functions into instead of a more procedural approach if you want to embrace C++.

Comment: john that sounds reasonable ill go over my code to make sure it makes a balanced tree. Tadman I have a class TreeType and a struct to make nodes for that TreeType, just didn't include it to keep the code short. I'll keep the nullptr tip in mind.

Comment: The problem is likely in the code which constructs the tree. Can you please show it? Have you tried inserting printouts in order to see at which step `false` is returned?

Comment: Mikhail just updated the post and in the sortedArray to bst you can see the long list of couts I did to check if everything places where it should be. when inputting "victorn" everything seems to go into the correct place. I will also try your suggestion to see where false is returned, though I am not sure where I can put the cout at to see that result

Comment: as far as I can tell the trees that are being produced seem to be balanced

Comment: @VictorNath What value do you pass as `l` to the function `sortedArrayToBST`? It seems, in the helper function `end` is the last element (and not the one after the last). If so, you should pass items size minus one in the second argument to `sortedArrayToBST`.

Comment: @Mikhail in the main function I called it as a.sortedArrayToBST(words, strlen(words)), words being the name of the sorted chars, so do you think I should pass strlen(words) - 1?

Comment: @Mikhail …...wow it worked. I've been stuck here for hours trying to fix it and never would have thought of this. Could you explain why it should be strlen(words) - 1 instead of strlen(words)? Is it because of the nullbyte character usually found in char arrays? Either way thanks so much man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"@VictorNath What value do you pass as l to the function sortedArrayToBST? It seems, in the helper function end is the last element (and not the one after the last). If so, you should pass items size minus one in the second argument to sortedArrayToBST."  - Mikhail

in summary solution was to subtract 1 from the length when calling sortedArrayBST

Comment: Glad that it helped!